# Describe the image and kernel of a projection

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, symmetric-matrices, transpose

**Question**

Consider the linear operator $P$ defined on $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ by

$P(A)$ = $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^{T})$

Show that $P$ is a projection, and describe its image and kernel.

I have shown that $P$ is a projection, but I'm a bit unsure about what is meant by "describe its image and kernel". The image and kernel of P are given by the sets:

$Im(P)$ = {$P(A)$ $∣$ A $\in$ $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$}

$Ker(P)$ = {$A$ $\in$ $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ $∣$ $P(A)$ = **$0$**}

Is there some sort of relationship between these sets that I'm supposed to describe?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Projection**:$P^2(A) = P(P(A)) = P(\frac{1}{2}(A + A^T)) = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1}{2}(A + A^T) + \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T)^T) = \frac{1}{4}(A + A^T + A^T + A) = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T) = P(A)$

**Kernel**: $P(A) = 0 \implies \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T) = 0 \implies A = -A^T$ i.e. *anti-symmetric matrices*

Kernel($P$) = {$A\in M_n(\mathbb{R}) : A=-A^T$}

**Image**: $\frac{1}{2}(A + A^T)$ is a *symmetric matrix* (since $(\frac{1}{2}(A + A^T))^T = \frac{1}{2}(A^T + A)$)

Image($P$) = {$A\in M_n(\mathbb{R}) : A=A^T$}

Comment: How do you arrive at $A$ = $A^{T}$ as a condition for the set of images of $P$?

Comment: $B = \frac{1}{2}(A + A^T)$. See that $B = B^T$

Comment: But how does that imply that $A$ = $A^{T}$? Shouldn't the Image of $P$ be instead:
Image($P$) = {$B$  $\in$ $M_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ : $B$ = $B^{T}$ }, where $B$ =  $\frac{1}{2}(A+A^{T})$ ?

Comment: We can write any symmetric matrix in the form of $\frac{1}{2} (A + A^T)$. Let S is a symmetric matrix, then $S =\frac{1}{2} (S + S) =  \frac{1}{2} (S + S^T)$ since $S = S^T$. This implies that the image is the set of all symmetric matrices

Comment: That makes more sense. Thank you so much for your help!